# stream.exceptions.FeedConfigException error

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, getstream-io

My backend Django REST Framework prints this error.

> stream.exceptions.FeedConfigException: The following feeds are not configured: 'user'. 
>       This could be the cause of a typo, but otherwise you should configure them on the dashboard of this app.

Here is my snippet of source code

```
class Post(models.Model, Activity):
    parent = models.ForeignKey("self", blank=True, null=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, null=True, blank=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=True)
    ...


    @property
    def activity_actor_attr(self):
        return self.user
```

I guess I need to create `user` feed in dashboard. But I don't understand why it's happening. user? feed? Should I put Activity to AUTH_USER_MODEL?? I don't have UserModel and I'm using the default UserModel.

:(

**UPDATE** I added `user` Feed and it solved the problem. And I don't see any row data.

I'm totally new in getStream() and need to learn it really fast.

Comment: Looks like you've solved the problem :) You're correct that a Feed Group needs to be created in the Stream dashboard before new feeds can be used by client applications. Per SO guidelines, it's recommended that you  answer your own question and mark it as the accepted answer.

Comment: thanks! why do I have to set the feed group name as 'user' and how do we set the other name???

Comment: On the Stream API side, Feed Groups can be given any name. When using the Django framework integration, by default the Feed Group is assumed to be 'user' or 'actor'. As you've seen, the `activity_actor_attr` property function will direct the integration to use a different field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added `user` Feed group and it solved the problem.